# Shortcut to delete currently opened file in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sidebar

Is there any shortcut to delete the currently opened file in Sublime 3?

I have installed the SideBarEnhancements, but it is a lot of work to right click on a file, select delete, confirm the popup and then again close the file and the popup, because the file has been deleted and I have some unsaved changes.

Comment: To remove files, SideBarEnhancements has right click -> Project -> Exclude from project

Answer (score 3):

The functions name to delete the selected file from the sidebar is named "side_bar_delete", so if you have SideBarEnhancements installed you can use this function. So my version for example is:

```
[
  {"keys": ["super+alt+backspace"], "command": "side_bar_delete"}
]
```

Paste it in the general user.sublime-keymap file.

Comment: it is working like a charm and should be marked as the solution

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Delete%20Current%20File) will delete the file and close the buffer, and you could bind the command to a key.

Note however there's a potential conflict with the SideBarEnhancements delete command, see the workaround described in the readme.